# ESRI.ArcGIS Map Load dynamic KMLs

Tags: .net, c#-2.0, kml, esri, esri-arc-engine

I'm loading the ESRI Map and the KML Layer Everything Works Fine!

**Problem :** After the KML Data changes(often changes), i am unable to show the New Changes in the Map. I need to forcefully
 Clear the Browser Cache every time.And I tried refreshing the layer did't work out.

My code

```
// Create a new KmlLayer object. 
  ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources.KmlLayer theKmlLayer = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources.KmlLayer();

  // Set the KmlLayer's ID.
  theKmlLayer.ID = "SampleData";

  // Set the Url of the KmlLayer. Note the Url takes a Uri object!
  theKmlLayer.Url = new Uri("localhost/KML/east.kml");//Here is the New KML Data

  // Need to use a ProxyUrl on the KmlLayer since the service is not hosted locally or on a local network.
  theKmlLayer.ProxyUrl = "http://serverapps.esri.com/SilverlightDemos/ProxyPage/proxy.ashx";

  // Add the KmlLayer to the Map. An automaic refresh of the Map and Legend Controls will occur.
  Map1.Layers.Add(theKmlLayer);
```

I tried **theKmlLayer.Refresh();**

Do i need to clear the Browser cache through code or is it possible to load the new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution to KML caching (and Google caches the data for a few hours on the server), is to use a random or time based cache busting parameter in the URL (so it is never the same).

one example of a cache busting parameter:

```
'?dummy=' + (new Date()).getTime());
```